# How can I fix the error "CS0029" in my Unity C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a script in my project but it keeps returning this error:

`Assets/Materials/assets/WorldGeneration.cs(79,41): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.GameObject to UnityEngine.Vector3`

This is all the code I have in my script (And I know the code is a mess):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Block
{
    public int type;
    public bool vis;

    public Block(int t, bool v)
    {
        type = t;
        vis = v;
    }
}

public class WorldGeneration : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public static int width = 128;
    public static int depth = 128;
    public static int height = 128;

    public int heightScale = 20;
    public float detailScale = 25.0f;

    public GameObject grassBlock;
    public GameObject sandBlock;
    public GameObject snowBlock;

    Block[,,] worldBlocks = new Block[width, height, depth];

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
{
    int seed = (int) Network.time * 10;
    for (int z = 0; z <= depth; z++) {

        for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++) {
            
            int y = (int) (Mathf.PerlinNoise((x+seed)/detailScale, (z+seed)/detailScale) * heightScale);
            Vector3 blockPos = new Vector3 (x, y, z);

            CreateBlock (y, blockPos, true);
            while (y > 0) {
                y--;
                blockPos = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
                CreateBlock(y, blockPos, false);    
            }
        }
    }
}

    // Use this for creating blocks
void CreateBlock(int y, Vector3 blockPos, bool create)
{
    if (y > 15) {
        if (create)
            Instantiate (snowBlock, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
        worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y,(int) (blockPos.z)] = new Block (1, create);
    } 
    else if (y > 5) {
        if (create)
            Instantiate (grassBlock, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
        worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z] = new Block (2, create);
    } 
    else {
        if (create)
            Instantiate (sandBlock, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
        worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z] = new Block (3, create);
    }
}

    // Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2.0f, Screen.height / 2.0f, 0));
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000.0f)) {
            
            Vector3 blockPos = hit.transform.gameObject.;

            //This is the bottom block. Don't delete it
            if((int)blockPos.y == 0) return;

            worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z] = null;

            Destroy (hit.transform.gameObject);


            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                    for (int z = -1; z <= 1; z++) {
                        if (!(x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0)) {
                            Vector3 neighbor = new Vector3 (blockPos.x + x, blockPos.y + y, blockPos.z + z);
                            DrawBlock (neighbor);
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
     
        // Use this for returing values
void DrawBlock(Vector3 blockPos)
{
    if (worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z] == null)
        return;

    if (!worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z].vis) {
        
        worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z].vis = true;
        if (worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z].type == 1)
            Instantiate (snowBlock, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
    } else if (worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z].type == 2)
        Instantiate (grassBlock, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
    else if (worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z].type == 3)
        Instantiate (sandBlock, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
    else
        worldBlocks [(int)blockPos.x, (int)blockPos.y, (int)blockPos.z].vis = false;
}

/* End Of Script*/
```

I tried debugging it by casting blockPos to a Vector3 like this:

```
Vector3 blockPos = (Vector3) hit.transform.gameObject;
```

Any ideas on what went wrong?

It seems as if the gameObject cannot be cast to a Vector3 and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the exception says, you have an error in your code. You're trying to save a GameObject in a Vector3.

Row 79:

```
 Vector3 blockPos = hit.transform.gameObject.;
```

This is not working code. You want:

```
Vector3 blockPos = hit.transform.position;
```

Comment: My answer still applies. You want to save the position of the transform, not the gameobject itself. hit.transform.position;

Comment: I doubt it's the same error. In the error in your original post you write "Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.GameObject to UnityEngine.Vector3". This means that you're trying to save a GameObject in a Vector3. Sort of like writing:

int number = "String value";

It doesn't compile because it's wrong. If the code I've written earlier (Vector3 blockPos = hit.transform.position;) doesn't work you have to tell me the new error, because there's no way you're gonna get the same error from that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Unity3D documentation, [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) inherits from `System.Object`. Also, according the documentation there is no implicit cast operator overload on `GameObject` or `Vector3` leaving this issue to a simple answer:

A `GameObject` is not a `Vector3` and cannot be explicitely casted to be one.

For a solution to your problem see the answer of Fredrik. He seems to know something about Unity3D and not only about .NET like me ;).